# Using fresh fruit for wine

Tags: flavor

I've recently been attempting to use fresh fruit to flavor my wines and have had disastrous results. The recipes I've found and copied all say to remove the fruit from the must after around 7 days and then let the must finish fermenting.
By doing this, the wine finishes with little to no fruit flavor. The recipes all call for around 12lbs/5gal batch. My SG and FG numbers fall well within the intended target, but there's little flavor and my blackberry came out hardly colored at all. I worry the fruit will rot in the must if left in any longer. What am I not doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advise would be to freeze the fruit before adding it, it causes the cell membranes and cell walls to become perforated by the expanding ice crystals allowing all the colour and flavour out.

I use this trick when making my 3 day sloe gin, no faffing around waiting for months.

I have also used this for elderberry stouts to get all the flavour out into the beer.